# wp_get_attachment_image returns different image size

Tags: functions, templates, ajax

It is a bug?

```
wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'post-thumb-size-small');
```

Same code, called in template, and in AJAX call returns same image SRC, but different image width and height.

dumb from template call:

```
<img width="286" height="189" src="http://localhost/site/files/2012/02/post-image-31-286x189.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumb-size-small" alt="post-image-3" title="post-image-3">
```

dump from AJAX call

```
<img width="220" height="145" src="http://localhost/site/files/2012/02/post-image-31-286x189.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumb-size-small" alt="post-image-3" title="post-image-3">
```

i'm confused, whats wrong?

index.php code

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php include 'post.php'; ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

post.php code

```
<div class="container">

<?php
if( in_array( $post_type, array( 'audio', 'video', 'quote', 'link'))) {
  $theme->theme_post->display_post_element( $post_type, $post_size, $post);
}
?>
</div>
```

display_post_element function code

```
    function display_post_element( $post_type, $post_size, $post) {
$attachment_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_view_attachment_id', true);
        if( $post_type == 'single_image') {
            $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full');

            if( is_array( $img)):                
            ?>
            <div class="preview-thumb">
                <a href="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>" class="lightbox"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'post-thumb-size-' . $post_size); ?></a>
                <a href="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>" class="lightbox zoom"></a>
            </div>
            <?php
            endif;
        }
}
```

load posts with ajax call code:

```
function load_posts_ajax() {
    global $post;
    $query_string = $_POST['query_string'];

    query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=' . get_option( 'posts_per_page') . '&post_status=publish&offset=' . (int)$_POST[ 'off']);

    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        include TEMPLATEPATH . '/post.php';
    endwhile; endif;

    die;
}
```

Comment: You added `'post-thumb-size-small'` as additional image size? Btw: Please update your Q with some more info about your ajax setup (code), etc.

Comment: @kaiser, of course i added this image size... I'll try to update the question in more details

Comment: Sometimes WP doesn't resize images properly and instead just puts width and height attributes on the `<img/>` element to force it to the size you wanted. Could your ajax be getting the "actual" image size instead?

Comment: If you added a new image size to your theme old images don't have the new image size yet. If that's the case it will return a different size. You can regenerate your thumbnails with a plugin like `Regenerate thumbnails`.

Comment: @Dominic +1 for the idea. Anyway, WP is getting the attributes from `$hwstring = image_hwstring($width, $height)`, which is nothing than formatting the outcoming of `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`.

Comment: @Rob Vermeer, all images are displayed correctly when called from a template, but wrong when called through Ajax

Comment: @Dominic it is possible to force only the width, and height is unknown, and whether is this the right solution? it's more like a "crutch" :D

Comment: Where are you defining the image sizes? I wonder if it's possible that they are not defined when doing Ajax.

Comment: @helenhousandi, i defined image sizes in functions.php in theme constructor

Comment: @helenhousandi it is the "after_setup_theme" action

Comment: @helenhousandi i dumped `get_intermediate_image_sizes()` and all image sizes are loaded in AJAX call

Answer (score 1):

#### Handle built in sizes right

I wrote a class that handles all the different stuff for built in image sizes.

2. To redefine the built in sizes, use an extended class (the upper file in the linked source)
3. To unset a class and skip it's useage completely, just set `w` & `h` to `0`.

[http://static.steffenvogel.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/octocat_construction.gif](https://gist.github.com/1853928)

<sup>Click the octocat to view the gist :)</sup>

Comment: +1+ for the octocat link :))) . . . . & of course, for the fine piece of code - [Dynamic Image Resize](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Dynamic-Image-Resize), aka Timthumb Done Right, is bloody cool as well!